# CodeIgniter, populate database table with data from another table, array to string conversion error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having trouble populating one of my database columns with data that is present in another table on the database. I want to populate a column of data in the second table with data found in the first table, but based off of data found in the second table. If this is unclear, I have tried to simplify it below.

I have two tables, one called assignments and one called submissions. The table submissions contains the columns (accountid, assignmenttitle, assignment and expectedoutcome). The table assignments contains the columns (assignmentname, assignmenttype, lecturername, assignmentdetails and expectedoutcome).

I have a form on the user interface for submitting assignments into the 'submissions' table, the first three columns of this table are populating just fine, my problem stands with the final column (expectedoutcome).

I have put the code I have the relates to this below, I keep getting the error 'Array to string conversion' when trying to submit the form, so even though the data does submit, the final column in the 'submissions' table has the entry 'Array' instead of the expected outcome of the assignment, which can be found in the 'assignments' table.

This block of code in the relating function in the Model, here the predefined variables of $code and $assignment are both taken from the user form on the relating view. $assignment also relates to the name of the assignment, which is selected via a dropdown on the corresponding View. The query to collect the expected outcome here is returning an array, rather than just the single entity I was expecting.

Model:

```
// saves user assignment in the backend database under 'submissions' table          
public function saveassignment($code, $assignment) 
{

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT expectedoutcome 
                                FROM assignments 
                                WHERE assignmentname = '$assignment'");
    return $query->result();

    $expectedoutcome = $query->result();
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');

    $query = "INSERT INTO submissions 
                VALUES ('$username','$assignment','$code',
                        '$expectedoutcome')";
    $this->db->query($query);
}
```

Controller:

```
// handles submission page
public function submission() 
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('system');

    $data['title'] = "Submit Assignment";
    $data['assignments'] = $this->system->assignmentnames();

    $this->load->view('submission', $data);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('testcode','Test Code','required');   

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('submission', $data);
    } else {
        $assignment = $this->input->post('assignmentname');
        $code = $this->input->post('testcode');
        $this->system->saveassignment($code, $assignment);
        echo "Code Saved Successfully";
        echo "<br /><a href='results'>View Results</a>";
    }
}
```

Table Schema

[image]

Comment: Did you notice that line 2 of your `saveassignment($code, $assignment)` function is a RETURN. So the remaining lines of code in that function will Never be Executed !!

Comment: I tried removing it, but that's not the problem, even without that, the database still inputs only 'Array' in the expected outcome field, rather than the actual expected outcome.

Comment: Just to answer your statement as well, the following lines of code do execute, it does input the data into the database, just doesn't get the final field correct.

Comment: Can you show us a schema for that table please?

Comment: I've just edited the link into the post.

Comment: I am pretty sure Codeigniter always returns an array of objects from a query when you use `->result()` so either expect an array or use one of the other dbhandle unloader functions https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

Comment: Okay, will have a look, thanks, I have other functions in my program that return results the same way, but due to them being present on the view I can loop through and display each result separately, I'm assuming that isn't possible when trying to populate a database table?